# Initializing primefaces datatable rowkey

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces datatable that I'm populating with properties of objects in an **ArrayList** once the user clicks a search button. I need to add a column with a radio button so that the user can select a row of the table to update. I'd like to set the rowkey to be the metadataKey property of my objects, but I get the following error:

> rowKey="#{result.metadataKey}": Property 'metadataKey' not found on
>   type java.lang.String

I believed that this was caused by the metadataKey not existing at the time the table is rendered. To remedy it, I set the table to render only after the user had completed their search, but this resulted in the same error.

Here is the relevant html:

```
<h:form id="dataForm">
    <p:panel styleClass="centered">
        <p:messages id="message" showDetails="true" autoUpdate="true" />
        <p:outputLabel id="searchLabel" value="Search for Metadata:  " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <p:inputText id="search"
            value="#{updateMetadataItemsBean.searchTerm}" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <p:commandButton id="searchButton" value="Search" 
            action="#{updateMetadataItemsBean.search}"
            update="dataForm:metadataitems, message, dataForm:dataPanel" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel styleClass="center" id="dataPanel" >
        <p:dataTable id="metadataitems" var="result"
            value="#{updateMetadataItemsBean.results}" styleClass="center"
            resizableColumns="true"
            selection="updateMetadataItemsBean.selectedMetadataItem"
            rowKey="#{result.metadataKey}" rendered="#{updateMetadataItemsBean.show}">              
            <p:column headerText="Select Item to Update" selectionMode="single"></p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Metadata Key">
                <h:outputText value="#{result.metadataKey}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Map Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{result.mapName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Metadata Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{result.metadataName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Metadata Value">
                <h:outputText value="#{result.metadataValue}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="WTX Adapter">
                <h:outputText value="#{result.wtxAdapter}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Card Number">
                <h:outputText value="#{result.cardNumber}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Create Date TS">
                <h:outputText value="#{result.createDateTS}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </p:panel>
```

This is the relevant code from the bean:

```
public class UpdateMetadataItemsBean implements Serializable{
public static final long serialVersionUID = 4;
private String metadataKey;
private String mapName;
private String metadataName;
private String metadataValue;
private String wtxAdapter;
private String cardNumber;
private String createDateTS;
private String searchTerm;
private String selectedDataKey;
private boolean show = false;
private MetadataItems selectedMetadataItem;
private ArrayList<MetadataItems> results = new ArrayList<MetadataItems>();

[getters and setters]

public void search() {
    Search s = new Search();
    setResults(s.search(searchTerm));

    setShow(true);
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Plus comment, alter `selection="updateMetadataItemsBean.selectedMetadataItem"` to `selection="#{updateMetadataItemsBean.selectedMetadataItem}"`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks @Lucas Costa !

Comment: In the `MetadataItems` has the get and setters for `metadataKey`? And the metadataKey has unique value?

Comment: Believe it or not, the problem was my incorrect reference that you mentioned in your first comment. I'm not sure how it produced that error, but fixing it solved the issue.

Comment: I add how response, for future search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter

`selection="updateMetadataItemsBean.selectedMetadataItem"`

to

`selection="#{updateMetadataItemsBean.selectedMetadataItem}"`.